# ошибка при создании функции в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    what = input("Что вычисляем? (плотность,обьём,масса)")

if what == "плотность":
    a = int(input("введите массу:"))
    b = int(input("введите обьем:"))
    c = a / b
    print("Ваш результат:" + str(c))

if what == "масса":
    a = int(input("введите плотность:"))
    b = int(input("введите обьём:"))
    c = a * b
    print("ваш результат:" + str(c))

if what == "обьём":
    a = int(input("введите массу:"))
    b = int(input("введите плотность:"))
    c = a / b
    print("ваш результат:" + str(c))
if (what !="объём" and what !="масса" and what !="плотность"):
    print("вы ввели неверную функцию")
```

Когда пытаюсь сделать из этого кода функцию выдаёт ошибку,прошу помощи

Comment: Как пытаешься - неизвестно. Какая ошибка - неизвестно. Какой помощи тогда просишь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вы хотели сделать так?

```
def math(what):
    if what == "плотность":
        a = int(input("введите массу:"))
        b = int(input("введите обьем:"))
        c = a / b
        print("Ваш результат:" + str(c))

    elif what == "масса":
        a = int(input("введите плотность:"))
        b = int(input("введите обьём:"))
        c = a * b
        print("ваш результат:" + str(c))

    elif what == "обьём":
        a = int(input("введите массу:"))
        b = int(input("введите плотность:"))
        c = a / b
        print("ваш результат:" + str(c))
    else:
        print("вы ввели неверную функцию")

what = input("Что вычисляем? (плотность,обьём,масса)")

math(what)
```

Comment: Кроме if есть еще и else, а проверка в самом последнем if вообще избыточна и ненужна.

Comment: Был дан код я его не менял превратив в функцию, теперь изменил

Comment: Никита,спасибо вам огромное,все работает!!